# Mysql "where not in" condition is very slow

Tags: mysql

The task is to exclude row by a group where the "word" field is NULL

Tables

```
CREATE TABLE `search_phrases` (
  `id` int unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `phrase` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `frequency` bigint NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `search_phrases_phrase_index` (`phrase`),
  KEY `search_phrases_frequency_index` (`frequency`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1000001 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

CREATE TABLE `search_words` (
  `id` int unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `word` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `search_words_word_unique` (`word`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=128287 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

CREATE TABLE `search_combinable` (
  `search_phrase_id` int unsigned NOT NULL,
  `search_word_id` int unsigned NOT NULL,
  KEY `search_combinable_search_phrase_id_foreign` (`search_phrase_id`),
  KEY `search_combinable_search_word_id_foreign` (`search_word_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `search_combinable_search_phrase_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`search_phrase_id`) REFERENCES `search_phrases` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `search_combinable_search_word_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`search_word_id`) REFERENCES `search_words` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

CREATE TABLE `requested_words` (
  `id` int unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `word` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `ts` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `requested_words_word_index` (`word`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=436 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

/* some sample data */
INSERT INTO search_phrases VALUES (1, 'men''s shorts', 1031588), (2, 'red shorts', 456000), (3, 'green shorts', 436000);
INSERT INTO search_words VALUES (1, 'men''s'), (2, 'shorts'), (3, 'red'), (4, 'green');
INSERT INTO search_combinable VALUES (1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 3), (2, 2), (3, 4), (3, 2);
INSERT INTO requested_words VALUES (1, 'men''s', '2023-03-01 07:45:49'), (2, 'shorts', '2023-03-01 07:45:49'), (3, 'red', '2023-03-01 07:45:49');
```

As a result, there should be phrases that contain words from the requested words table

```
select sp.id, sp.phrase, sp.frequency from search_phrases as sp
inner join search_combinable as sc on sc.search_phrase_id = sp.id
inner join search_words as sw on sw.id = sc.search_word_id
inner join requested_words as rw on rw.word = sw.word
where sp.id not in (
    select sp.id from search_phrases as temp_sp
    inner join search_combinable as sc on sc.search_phrase_id = temp_sp.id
    inner join search_words as sw on sw.id = sc.search_word_id
    left join requested_words as rw on rw.word = sw.word
    where rw.word is null and temp_sp.id = sp.id
)
group by sp.id
order by sp.frequency desc
```

The execution time is about 29 seconds. It grows in proportion to the increase in the "request_table"

```
| id | select_type | table   | partitions | type   | possible_keys                                                                       | key                                        | key_len | ref                         | rows | filtered | Extra                                        |
|----|-------------|---------|------------|--------|-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|--------------------------------------------|---------|-----------------------------|------|----------|----------------------------------------------|
| 1  | SIMPLE      | rw      |            | index  | requested_words_word_index                                                          | requested_words_word_index                 | 1022    |                             | 435  | 100      | Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort |
| 1  | SIMPLE      | sw      |            | eq_ref | PRIMARY,search_words_word_unique                                                    | search_words_word_unique                   | 1022    | laravel.rw.word             | 1    | 100      | Using index                                  |
| 1  | SIMPLE      | sc      |            | ref    | search_combinable_search_phrase_id_foreign,search_combinable_search_word_id_foreign | search_combinable_search_word_id_foreign   | 4       | laravel.sw.id               | 17   | 100      |                                              |
| 1  | SIMPLE      | sp      |            | eq_ref | PRIMARY,search_phrases_phrase_index,search_phrases_frequency_index                  | PRIMARY                                    | 4       | laravel.sc.search_phrase_id | 1    | 100      |                                              |
| 1  | SIMPLE      | temp_sp |            | eq_ref | PRIMARY                                                                             | PRIMARY                                    | 4       | laravel.sc.search_phrase_id | 1    | 100      | Using where; Not exists; Using index         |
| 1  | SIMPLE      | sc      |            | ref    | search_combinable_search_phrase_id_foreign,search_combinable_search_word_id_foreign | search_combinable_search_phrase_id_foreign | 4       | laravel.sc.search_phrase_id | 2    | 100      |                                              |
| 1  | SIMPLE      | sw      |            | eq_ref | PRIMARY                                                                             | PRIMARY                                    | 4       | laravel.sc.search_word_id   | 1    | 100      |                                              |
| 1  | SIMPLE      | rw      |            | ref    | requested_words_word_index                                                          | requested_words_word_index                 | 1022    | laravel.sw.word             | 4    | 100      | Using where; Using index                     |
```

**Dataset**

search_phrases

| id | phrase | frequency |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | men's shorts | 1031588 |
| 2 | red shorts | 456000 |
| 3 | green shorts | 436000 |

search_combinable

| search_phrase_id | search_word_id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 3 |
| 2 | 2 |
| 3 | 4 |
| 3 | 2 |

search_words

| id | word |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | men's |
| 2 | shorts |
| 3 | red |
| 4 | green |

requested_words

| id | word | ts |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | men's | 2023-03-01 07:45:49 |
| 2 | shorts | 2023-03-01 07:45:49 |
| 3 | red | 2023-03-01 07:45:49 |

in the response, I expect to see the phrases: **men's shorts** and **red shorts**

**P.S**
After adding the primary key to the search_combinable table

```
CREATE TABLE `search_combinable` (
  `search_phrase_id` int unsigned NOT NULL,
  `search_word_id` int unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`search_word_id`,`search_phrase_id`),
  KEY `search_combinable_search_word_id_search_phrase_id_index` (`search_word_id`,`search_phrase_id`),
  KEY `search_combinable_search_phrase_id_foreign` (`search_phrase_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `search_combinable_search_phrase_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`search_phrase_id`) REFERENCES `search_phrases` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `search_combinable_search_word_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`search_word_id`) REFERENCES `search_words` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

```
select sp.id, sp.phrase, sp.frequency
from search_phrases as sp
where not exists (
    select 1
    from search_phrases sp2
    left join search_combinable as sc on sc.search_phrase_id = sp2.id
    left join search_words as sw on sw.id = sc.search_word_id
    left join requested_words as rw on rw.word = sw.word
    where sp2.id = sp.id
    and rw.word is null
)
order by sp.frequency desc;
```

| id | select_type | table | partitions | type | possible_keys | key | key_len | ref | rows | filtered | Extra |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | SIMPLE | sw |  | index | PRIMARY | search_words_word_unique | 1022 |  | 43359 | 100 | Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort |
| 1 | SIMPLE | rw |  | ref | requested_words_word_index | requested_words_word_index | 1022 | laravel.sw.word | 4 | 100 | Using index |
| 1 | SIMPLE | sc |  | ref | PRIMARY,search_combinable_search_word_id_search_phrase_id_index,search_combinable_search_phrase_id_foreign | search_combinable_search_word_id_search_phrase_id_index | 4 | laravel.sw.id | 18 | 100 | Using index |
| 1 | SIMPLE | sp |  | eq_ref | PRIMARY,search_phrases_phrase_index,search_phrases_frequency_index | PRIMARY | 4 | laravel.sc.search_phrase_id | 1 | 100 |  |

Comment: be very (very!) careful of `not in` which can give misleading results due to NULLs

Comment: I don't understand why, the execution time is huge. Yes, the table has 1m records, but that's not the reason

Comment: My comment wasn't about performance - but accuracy. You can get incorrect results using "not on" so I suggest you avoid it altogether

Comment: Please add a more detailed explanation of what you are trying to achieve, the relevant DDL and the `EXPLAIN` output for your query. An example with a small sample of data and the expected result would help explain.

Comment: Please add the execution plan **in text form** (not hidden in a screenshot!), along with the `CREATE TABLE`  statements for all relevant tables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your junction table `search_combinable` has no PK and is not indexed properly. It should be:

```sql
CREATE TABLE `search_combinable` (
    `search_phrase_id` int unsigned NOT NULL,
    `search_word_id` int unsigned NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`search_phrase_id`, `search_word_id`),
    KEY `idx_search_combinable_word_phrase` (`search_word_id`, `search_phrase_id`),
    CONSTRAINT `fk_search_combinable_search_phrase_id` FOREIGN KEY (`search_phrase_id`) REFERENCES `search_phrases` (`id`),
    CONSTRAINT `fk_search_combinable_search_word_id` FOREIGN KEY (`search_word_id`) REFERENCES `search_words` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

It may be that the PK and reverse should be the other way around. You can experiment with your dataset and known queries.

The best I have come up with so far is:

```sql
select sp.*
from (
    select sc.search_phrase_id
    from search_combinable sc
    join search_words sw on sc.search_word_id = sw.id
    left join requested_words rw on sw.word = rw.word
    group by sc.search_phrase_id
    having count(distinct sw.id) = count(distinct rw.word)
) t
join search_phrases sp on t.search_phrase_id = sp.id
order by sp.frequency desc;
```

With your test dataset it returns 47 rows in 0.93 - 0.97 seconds.

I managed to squeeze a tiny bit off by pre-joining `search_words` and `requested_words` but YMMV:

```sql
select sp.*
from (
    select sc.search_phrase_id
    from search_combinable sc
    join (
        select sw.id, count(rw.id) > 0 AS req
        from search_words sw
        left join requested_words rw on sw.word = rw.word
        group by sw.id
    ) t on sc.search_word_id = t.id
    group by sc.search_phrase_id
    having count(t.id) = count(nullif(t.req, 0))
) t
join search_phrases sp on t.search_phrase_id = sp.id
order by sp.frequency desc;
```

0.68 - 0.70 seconds

Comment: it did not give any result

Answer (score 0):

Remove all the redundancy, all of those tables are involved in the query - you don't also need another set of joins etc. in the where clause:

```
select 
    temp_sp.id, temp_sp.phrase, temp_sp.frequency 
from search_phrases as temp_sp
inner join search_combinable as sc on sc.search_phrase_id = temp_sp.id
inner join search_words as sw on sw.id = sc.search_word_id
inner join requested_words as rw on rw.word = sw.word
where rw.word IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: I need to leave "phrases" where after join all "words" have non-null

Comment: there is a phrase "men's t-shirt" the words "t-shirt" and "men's" should be found if only "t-shirt" is found, then the phrase should be excluded

Comment: I need to see data to better understand your comments. All I can see are some table and column names; you however can also see data and know the requirements intimately - which I don't

Comment: re: `there is a phrase "men's t-shirt" the words "t-shirt" and "men's" should be found if only "t-shirt" is found, then the phrase should be excluded` truly - you need to supply "sample data" and and "expected result" from that data

Comment: the number of words in the "requested words" table can be quite large. I need to pick up all the phrases that contain combinations of these words. If there is a word in the phrase that does not exist in the requested word table, then this phrase is discarded.

Comment: Sample data. No matter how hard you try, no description will properly substitute fir samples of data. Those samples don't need to be large as long as they are faithfully representative of the information.